# Cannot convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<int>' to 'int'

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I have a problem sending data from the database to a list in the Controller. I am new to C# and MVC so any help will be useful! Code follows

```
public static List<FilterTree> GetAllUsers()
    {
        FilterTreeDBContext db = new FilterTreeDBContext();
        var userList = new List<FilterTree>();
        var device =  new FilterTree();
        //This is the line where I get the error
        device.ID = from a in db.FilterTree select a.ID;

        userList.Add(device);
        return userList;
    }
```

Thanks & Happy Holidays!! :)

Comment: Whats the problem officer?

Comment: FilterTree is your dbset. So from your query you are getting a list of integers. What is the type of instance variable ID in FilterTree? I guess it is int as evident from the error you are getting. You are trying to store a list (Iqueryable<int>) to a int field. I hope this analysis will help you fix your problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
device.ID = (from a in db.FilterTree select a.ID).First();
```

Linq query is lazy, and executes only after you request the value

BTW don't forgot to close the context, otherwise you will leak connections

```
using (var db = new FilterTreeDBContext())
{
    ...
    return userList;
}
```

Comment: @Mihai-CristianRotariu, with that being the case, make sure to accept it as the answer when the time has elapsed.

Answer (score 2):

As far as the frameworks knows that query may have more than one object so use it like this:

```
device.ID = (from a in db.FilterTree select a.ID).FirstOrDefault();
```